# How can I update a user field using this function on sign up in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to update field CustomUser (Custom User Model) field Origin_ip with a function like this, **where would I place and call this?**

```py
    def get_client_signup_ip(reuqest):
        g = GeoIP2()
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)

        return ip
```

I've tried placing this in my forms.py but **request is not defined there**, so I am unable to pass it. I'm not sure how to properly call this function from views.py in order to update a user field.

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),

]
```

**forms.py**

```py
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")


    def save(self, commit=True, request=True): # what is request=True doing here?
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```py
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

**ANSWER**
**Add in views.py under Form View class:**

```py
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs
```

**Update forms.py under `class Meta`**

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_client_signup_ip(self):
        g = GeoIP2()
        x_forwarded_for = self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)
        else: #HAVE SOMETHING HERE TO POP[ULATE THE ORIGIN FIELDS WITH A MESSAGE THAT THEY  WERE NTO FETCHED.
            ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)

        return ip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First, send the `request` object from view to template via [**`get_form_kwargs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) method:

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs
```

Now, you can capture the `request` in form:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_client_signup_ip(self):  # making this method as object method
        g = GeoIP2()
        x_forwarded_for = self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)
        else:
            ip = self.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            ip2 = '192.227.139.106'
            city = g.city(ip2)

        return ip


    def save(self, commit=True, request=True): # what is request=True doing here?
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.ip = self.get_client_signup_ip()  # setting the user attribute(ip)
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I am getting ```name 'request' is not defined```

```forms.py in get_client_signup_ip, line 31```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help I finally got this to work!!! I missed the ```self.request.META``` at first!